# How to get totalsize of files in directory?

Tags: node.js

How to get totalsize of files in directory ? Best way ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using the core Nodejs fs libraries combined with the async library. It is fully asynchronous and should work just like the 'du' command.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    async = require('async');

function readSizeRecursive(item, cb) {
  fs.lstat(item, function(err, stats) {
    if (!err && stats.isDirectory()) {
      var total = stats.size;

      fs.readdir(item, function(err, list) {
        if (err) return cb(err);

        async.forEach(
          list,
          function(diritem, callback) {
            readSizeRecursive(path.join(item, diritem), function(err, size) {
              total += size;
              callback(err);
            }); 
          },  
          function(err) {
            cb(err, total);
          }   
        );  
      }); 
    }   
    else {
      cb(err);
    }   
  }); 
}
```

Comment: `path.join(item, diritem)` is correct? When I launch the function, it returns `TypeError: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined`

Comment: Did you load the `path` module?

Comment: No. I think is better to clearly show loading all necessary modules in the code.

Comment: You want to add checks for `err` first thing in `lstat` and `readdir` callbacks. Something like `if (err) return cb(null,0)`, with some logging possibly. That will save you from exceptions when some inner directories are inaccessible to current user.

Comment: Have anyone had a chance to compare the speed against `du -sh` via `child_process`?

Comment: This seems to barf a NaN at me when using a directory of a single file and no sub-directories.

Answer (score 5):

I tested the following code and it works perfectly fine.
Please do let me know if there is anything that you don't understand.

```
var util  = require('util'),
spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
size    = spawn('du', ['-sh', '/path/to/dir']);

size.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('size: ' + data);
});


// --- Everything below is optional ---

size.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

size.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

[Courtesy Link](http://mandrivausers.org/index.php?/topic/3995-how-to-get-total-size-of-directory-in-shell/)

2nd method:

```
var util = require('util'), exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('du -sh /path/to/dir', function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null){
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

You might want to refer the Node.js API for [child_process](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/child_processes.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use du : https://www.npmjs.org/package/du

```
require('du')('/home/rvagg/.npm/', function (err, size) {
  console.log('The size of /home/rvagg/.npm/ is:', size, 'bytes')
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer maintained.

Comment: Last update was in June, so it seems, it is maintained (again)

Answer (score 3):

ES6 variant:

```
import path_module from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

// computes a size of a filesystem folder (or a file)
export function fs_size(path, callback)
{
    fs.lstat(path, function(error, stats)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            return callback(error)
        }

        if (!stats.isDirectory())
        {
            return callback(undefined, stats.size)
        }

        let total = stats.size

        fs.readdir(path, function(error, names)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                return callback(error)
            }

            let left = names.length

            if (left === 0)
            {
                return callback(undefined, total)
            }

            function done(size)
            {
                total += size

                left--
                if (left === 0)
                {
                    callback(undefined, total)
                }
            }

            for (let name of names)
            {
                fs_size(path_module.join(path, name), function(error, size)
                {
                    if (error)
                    {
                        return callback(error)
                    }

                    done(size)
                })
            }
        }) 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Review the node.js [File System functions](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.7/api/fs.html).  It looks like you can use a combination of [`fs.readdir(path, [cb])`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.7/api/fs.html#fs.readdir), and [`fs.stat(file, [cb])`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.7/api/fs.html#fs.stat) to list the files in a directory and sum their sizes.

Something like this (totally untested):

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('/path/to/dir', function(err, files) {
  var i, totalSizeBytes=0;
  if (err) throw err;
  for (i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    fs.stat(files[i], function(err, stats) {
      if (err) { throw err; }
      if (stats.isFile()) { totalSizeBytes += stats.size; }
    });
  }
});
// Figure out how to wait for all callbacks to complete
//   e.g. by using a countdown latch, and yield total size
//   via a callback.
```

Note that this solution only considers the plain files stored directly in the target directory and performs no recursion.  A recursive solution would come naturally by checking `stats.isDirectory()` and entering, although it likely complicates the "wait for completion" step.

Comment: This solution needs the relative path included in the fs.stat call or you'll get ENOENT errors.

Comment: `Figure out how to wait for all callbacks to complete` the most simple way is using a Promise-based library and using `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 1):

```
'use strict';

const async = require('async');
const fs    = require('fs');
const path  = require('path')

const getSize = (item, callback) => {
  let totalSize = 0;

  fs.lstat(item, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    if (stats.isDirectory()) {

      fs.readdir(item, (err, list) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);

        async.each(list, (listItem, cb) => {

          getSize(path.join(item, listItem), (err, size) => {
            totalSize += size;
            cb();
          });

        },
        (err) => {
          if (err) return callback(err);

          callback(null, totalSize);
        });

      });

    } else {
     // Ensure fully asynchronous API
      process.nextTick(function() {
        callback(null, (totalSize += stats.size))
      });
    }

  });

}

getSize('/Applications', (err, totalSize) => { if (!err) console.log(totalSize); });
```

Answer (score 1):

This combines [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) and the [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api) introduced in Node.js v14.0.0 for a clean, readable implementation:

```js
const { readdir, stat } = require('fs/promises');

const dirSize = async directory => {
  const files = await readdir( directory );
  const stats = files.map( file => stat( path.join( directory, file ) ) );

  let size = 0;
  for await ( const stat of stats ) size += stat.size;
  return size;
};
```

Usage:

```js
const size = await dirSize( '/path/to/directory' );
console.log( size );
```

---

An shorter-but-less-readable alternative of the `dirSize` function would be:

```js
const dirSize = async directory => {
  const files = await readdir( directory );
  const stats = files.map( file => stat( path.join( directory, file ) ) );

  return ( await Promise.all( stats ) ).reduce( ( accumulator, { size } ) => accumulator + size, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the part but I though I'd include my solution which uses promises based on @maerics answer:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

var totalSizeBytes=0;

fs.readdir('storage', function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;

    Promise.mapSeries(files, function(file){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.stat('storage/' + file,function(err, stats) {
                if (err) { throw err; }
                if (stats.isFile()) { totalSizeBytes += stats.size; resolve(); }
            });
        })
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log(totalSizeBytes);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function readSizeRecursive(folder, nested = 0) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const stats = fs.lstatSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../projects/', folder));
    var total = stats.size;
    const list = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../projects/', folder));
    if(list.length > 0){
      Promise.all(list.map(async li => {
        const stat = await fs.lstatSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../projects/', folder, li));
        if(stat.isDirectory() && nested == 0){
          const tt = await readSizeRecursive(folder, 1);
          total += tt;
        } else {
          total += stat.size;
        }
      })).then(() => resolve(convertBytes(total)));
    } else {
      resolve(convertBytes(total));
    }
  });
}

const convertBytes = function(bytes) {
  const sizes = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"]

  if (bytes == 0) {
    return "n/a"
  }

  const i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)))

  if (i == 0) {
    return bytes + " " + sizes[i]
  }

  // return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + " " + sizes[i]
  return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1));
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple synchronous solution that I implemented.

```
const fs = require("fs");
function getSize(path){
// Get the size of a file or folder recursively
let size = 0;
if(fs.statSync(path).isDirectory()){
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    files.forEach(file => {
        size += getSize(path + "/" + file);
    });
}
else{
    size += fs.statSync(path).size;
}
return size;
}
```