# Node.js: checking for file existence before writing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know from here that the official position is to not check for existence before manipulating a file: [Node.js check exist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699599/node-js-check-exist-file) Rather, one should simply attempt the write and handle whatever exceptions may be thrown.

However, my scenario is that I want to only write a certain file to a folder given that the file does not already exist. If the file exists, I want to do nothing.

What would be the idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use the `fs.stat` as described in an answer to the question you linked.

Comment: Alright. Is `fs.stat` guaranteed to return an error _only_ when the file doesn't exist?

Comment: No. But it is guaranteed to return the specific error `'ENOENT'` (error: no entry) *only* when the file doesn't exist. Again, see FÔx Gênki's answer on the linked question.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that detail. Thank you! Although I must say that semantically, this is atrocious. I will pretty much have to wrap it in my own sanely named function for it to make any kind of sense to someone reading the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback).

```
fs.exists('/path/to.file', function (exists) {
  if (!exists) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.stat('path-to-your-file', function(err) {  
    if (err) {
       // file does not exist
    } else {
        // file exists
    }
});
```

Comment: Am I guaranteed to get an error _only_ in the case I am looking for—that the file doesn't exist? Or might I get false negatives?