# How to check if file exist before appending data into it using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a case where once user download a file i am deleting it from the directory, Now once new message comes in its still trying to append to the file that does not exist , How can i check if obj.file exist then only append ?

server.js

```
recordLogs: function (obj) {
    var path = './app/records/templogs'
    var fileAppend = path + '/'+ obj.file;
    console.log('data from recoring', obj.data);
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
        items.forEach(function(file){
            if(obj.file === file){
                fs.appendFile(fileAppend, obj.data, null, 'utf8', function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
                console.log('filename in records',obj.file);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js check exist file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699599/node-js-check-exist-file)

Comment: It looks like what you're asking for is already accomplished by your code.  What problem are you encountering?

Comment: As i mentioned in my question when file is deleted , its still trying to append.

Comment: did you try using fs.stat(fileName, cb) ?