# I want to check if this file in this directory existing or not

Tags: node.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const images="images"
const path ='images\palmtunnel.jpg'
if(fs.existsSync(path)){
    console.log('exist')
}
else{
    console.log('does not exist')
}
```

[image]

this way didn't work just working in the files in the same directory.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699599/node-js-check-if-file-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699599/node-js-check-if-file-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using '/' intead of '\' ?
So your path will be:

```
const path = 'images/palmtunnel.jpg'
```

The backslash (\) is an escape character in Javascript (along with a lot of other C-like languages). This means that when Javascript encounters a backslash, it tries to escape the following character. For instance, \n is a newline character (rather than a backslash followed by the letter n). -Daniel
[JavaScript backslash (\) in variables is causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error)