Error creating folders in node.js with express and multer
I'm trying to do a server with node.js using express and multer, in which I can send an identifier and 12 photos to be stored in a folder. I'm using a multipart formdata but I'm facing a problem when creating directories dynamically.
The identifier that receives the server will be the last folder to create, and when to store de photos.
I have the next folders in my server:
/Users/vmartin/SourceCode/CerambyxApi/httpdocs/cerambyx_data/received/
/Users/vmartin/SourceCode/CerambyxApi/httpdocs/cerambyx_data/only_segmented/

then when I receive the request, I need to use the identifier sended to create a folder before the files are stored, so for exmaple:
identifier: 7ee1a048-f81f-4a

Server need to create
"/Users/vmartin/SourceCode/CerambyxApi/httpdocs/cerambyx_data/received/7ee1a048-f81f-4a/"

But I'm getting an error when testing it from postman.
This is my controller code.
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const router = express.Router();
const { uploadCollection } = require('../controllers/controller_upload_collection');

const destinationPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'cerambyx_data', 'received');

// Configuración de Multer para subida de archivos
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: async function (req, file, cb) {
      const identifier = req.body.identifier;
      const receivedDir = path.join(destinationPath, identifier); // Ruta completa

      try {
          // Verificar si la carpeta de destino existe
          const destinationStats = await fs.promises.stat(destinationPath);

          // Si no existe, intentar crearla
          if (!destinationStats.isDirectory()) {
              await fs.promises.mkdir(destinationPath, { recursive: true });
              console.log('Carpeta base de destino creada:', destinationPath);
          }

          // Verificar si la subcarpeta específica existe
          const receivedStats = await fs.promises.stat(receivedDir);

          // Si no existe, intentar crearla
          if (!receivedStats.isDirectory()) {
              await fs.promises.mkdir(receivedDir, { recursive: true });
              console.log('Subcarpeta específica de destino creada:', receivedDir);
          }

          // Llamar al callback de Multer con la ruta completa
          cb(null, receivedDir);
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error al verificar o crear la carpeta de destino:', error);
          cb(error); // Llamar al callback con el error
      }
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});


  
const upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 30 * 1024 * 1024 }, // 30MB por archivo
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        // Aquí puedes agregar lógica de filtrado si es necesario
        cb(null, true);
    }
});

// Ruta para subir fotos
router.post('/', upload.array('photos', 12), uploadCollection);

module.exports = { uploadCollectionRouter: router };

The error returned by node.js is:
Error al verificar o crear la carpeta de destino: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/vmartin/SourceCode/CerambyxApi/httpdocs/cerambyx_data/received/7ee1a048-f81f-4a'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/vmartin/SourceCode/CerambyxApi/httpdocs/cerambyx_data/received/7ee1a048-f81f-4a'
}


You are not checking that the directory exists before calling
const destinationStats = await fs.promises.stat(destinationPath);

Since there is no fs.promises.exists method, you can write a little helper to check if the file exists by doing this:
const fileExists = async (path) => {
try {
    await fs.access(path);
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}

};
Then you can check if the path exists before trying to create it or access it:
const directoryExists = await fileExists(destinationPath);
if (!directoryExists) {
    await fs.promises.mkdir(destinationPath, { recursive: true}): 
}


Thank you for your answer, but show me the next error:
Error al verificar o crear la carpeta de destino: TypeError: fs.promises.exists is not a function
at DiskStorage.destination [as getDestination] (/Users/vmartin/SourceCode/CerambyxApi/httpdocs/routes/upload_collection.js:20:50)
...
TypeError: fs.promises.exists is not a function
at DiskStorage.destination [as getDestination] (/Users/vmartin/SourceCode/CerambyxApi/httpdocs/routes/upload_collection.js:20:50)

You can use this strategy then to check if your file exists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76395273/14360814 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77370688/14360814
